# Applying for UK VISA - TLS UKVI MUP PRODUCT

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am applying for UK VISA from Italy (Pakistani National). On the TLS Website, it says UKVI MUP PRODUCT charge of €65.87. Do we know what this is? And how to take it off? As previously when i applied in 2013 it was all free?

Comment: Are you using the correct online application https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply ?

Comment: yes, that's the exact website. via the gov.uk website. application went through fine, when it asked me to book appointment, it was adding that charge?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue when I tried applying. Did you manage to get some clarity on what is that additional cost?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137439/tls-visa-center-ukvi-mup-product

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TLS visa center ukvi mup product](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137439/tls-visa-center-ukvi-mup-product)

Answer (score 3):

MUP: User Pays Fee*. An additional fee of £55 is required to use this location.

*This fee is for the acceptance or processing of a claim or application, or the provision of a service or process in connection with immigration or nationality at a place other than consular premises, where this is done outside the United Kingdom and in a User Pays Visa Application Centre