# TLS visa center ukvi mup product

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, netherlands

what exactly is this UKVI service MUP product and why it is asking for another €66.88 after I have paid my visa fee?

I am applying in the Netherlands

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have found it

MUP: User Pays Fee*. An additional fee of £55 is required to use this location.
*This fee is for the acceptance or processing of a claim or application, or the provision of a service or process in connection with immigration or nationality at a place other than consular premises, where this is done outside the United Kingdom and in a User Pays Visa Application Centre

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton bottom of this page https://pos.tlscontact.com/tls-service-options#mup-ftu